# JComboBox how to remove editor

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I want to remove the editor from a JComboBox to make the arrow button span
the entire width of the box.

I tried to use a custom ComboBoxUI to set the size and color of the arrow button.
This partially works, but because i couldn't figure out how to remove the editor,
the button is only half the width of the entire box.

**The main class:**

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
public class Box {
    public Box() {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("frame");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(400,250);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(null);
        frame.add(panel);

        String[] items = { "", "item1", "item2", "item3", "item4" };
        JComboBox<String> box = new JComboBox<>(items);
        box.setBounds(100,20,200,50);
        UIManager.put("ComboBox.squareButton", Boolean.FALSE);
        box.setUI(new ComboUI());
        box.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(2,2,2,2, Color.BLACK));
        panel.add(box);

        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Box();
    }
}
```

**And the custom ComboBoxUI:**

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicComboBoxUI;
import java.awt.*;
public class ComboUI extends BasicComboBoxUI {
        @Override
        protected JButton createArrowButton() {
            final JButton button = new JButton("Items");
            button.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
            button.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
            button.setBounds(0,0, 200,40);
            return button;
        }
    }
```

This code results in this:

Arrow button half the size of combo box"

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxCd4.png]

What i would like instead is this:

Arrow button same size as combo box:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VsTGv.png]

Comment: note: null layout (along with hard-coding sizes/locationsl is __wrong__

Comment: Why?  So many questions.  How do you intend to display the selected item to the user?  I'd consider starting with just a button and working up a custom solution from there

Comment: @MadProgrammer The selected item will be displayed to the user somewhere else. The reason i didn't want a custom solution is because i assumed there is an easy way to override either the size of the editor and set it to "0", or disable it completely.
I did try to set it's size by overriding the configureEditor method, but that didn't help.

Comment: Consider the intend of the component.  It's designed to be a compound component which shows the currently selected "selected item" and provide a means for the user to select a different item, all in a visually compact manner.  It's a self contained package, so, no I don't think there'd be an easy way to simply break it - especially when you also add in the UI delegate, which could easily implement the functionality it's own way.  Personally, I'd just start with a button `[...]` and go from there, but I'd still have questions over it's usefulness and UX acceptability from the users perspective

Comment: One idea is to use a `JButton` and a [Popup](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/Popup.html) together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created the following GUI using a `JButton` and a `Popup` from the `PopupFactory`.

[image: Example]

There's a `JLabel` at the top to show the selection and a `JButton` to show the item options.  Unfortunately, I couldn't print the GUI when the item list is displayed.

When you left-click the `JButton`, the list of items appear under the `JButton`.  When you select an item, the list disappears and the selected item is displayed.

This is a proof of concept.  You would need to add code to hide the list when the Esc key is pressed to cancel the list, as one example.

Here's the complete runnable code.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Point;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.ListSelectionModel;
import javax.swing.Popup;
import javax.swing.PopupFactory;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class ItemSelectorExample implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new ItemSelectorExample());
    }

    private int margin;

    private JButton button;

    private JFrame frame;

    private JLabel label;

    private JPanel buttonPanel;

    private Popup popup;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        this.margin = 5;

        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        this.buttonPanel = createButtonPanel();
        frame.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel createButtonPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(margin, margin, margin,
                margin));

        label = new JLabel(" ");
        panel.add(label, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        button = new JButton("Items");
        button.addActionListener(event -> {
            popup = createItemSelectionPanel();
            popup.show();
        });
        panel.add(button, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        return panel;
    }

    private Popup createItemSelectionPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(margin, margin, margin,
                margin));

        String[] items = new String[9];
        for (int index = 0; index < items.length; index++) {
            items[index] = "Item " + (index + 1);
        }

        JList<String> list = new JList<>(items);
        list.setVisibleRowCount(4);
        list.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        list.addListSelectionListener(event -> {
            String item = (String) list.getSelectedValue();
            label.setText(item);
            popup.hide();
        });
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(list);
        Dimension sp = scrollPane.getPreferredSize();
        Dimension bp = buttonPanel.getSize();
        Dimension b = button.getPreferredSize();
        Point s = button.getLocationOnScreen();

        int width = bp.width - margin - margin;
        scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, sp.height));

        PopupFactory factory = PopupFactory.getSharedInstance();
        Popup popup = factory.getPopup(panel, scrollPane, s.x, s.y + b.height);

        return popup;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll start from this and see if i can make it work almost like a JComboBox.

Comment: hmm .. astonished that panel.getWidth returns anything useful before showing (but: too long ago that I really got my hands dirty with swing :). Anyway, instead of setting the pref once I would try to hook into the showing event of the popup and calc the size dynamically (as combo/ui does, afair)

Comment: @kleopatra: I generate the `Popup` after I show the GUI.  If I was really trying to create this button list component, I'd probably look at the source for a `JComboBox` and see how that's done.

Comment: you are right, you do create it after showing - my bad ;)